# Draw unknown "Cloud" circuit in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, cloud

I wanted to draw an unknown part of the circuit with a kind of "cloud" as shown in the left part of  figure below. I was wondering what is the best way to do it in Circuitikz?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cloud`-shaped node. I made efforts to reproduce your circuit in detail.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,4) coordinate(p1)  to[resistor, l=$R$] (4,4)
  to[battery1, l=$V$] (4,0) -- (0,0) coordinate(p2); 
 \node[draw,cloud,cloud puffs=20,cloud puff arc=120,
    fill=gray!20,fit=(p1)(p2),aspect=0.2]{}; 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks TikZling, that would do the job :)